# Autocomplete with suggestions and source only accept

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete

[image]

I would like to create a autocomplete text box like the one shown in the picture. I know query ui provides autocomplete boxes, but none of them provides the functionality I need. Has anyone got some tutorials on how to create such a autocomplete box?

thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jquery select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) provides the required functionality. It's not an jquery.ui widget, but a standalone plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I was looking for. I got just one question how can I set values into a initialized box, lets say I want to fill the select box with values I have saved in a DB